# Apple two factor always thinks my device is a "new device"?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I have two-factor authentication enabled on my Apple accounts. The problem is that every single time, it thinks my device is a "new device". I added [*.]apple.com to my cookies whitelist at

```
chrome://settings/content/cookies?search=cookies
```

But it doesn't seem to help. It still thinks my Mac is a new device, every single time.

What to I need to do to get two-factor to remember my Mac?